# Push Notification not working ios 8.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, ios8.3

I have integrated Azure notification in my project.Push notification working iOS 9 above iOS 8.3 notification not working.
This is my code AppDelegate code sample:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)){
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }else{
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

}
```

Comment: you have use third party (Azure notification) class?

Comment: Yes Rohit. I am using WindowsAzureMessaging.Framework.

Answer (score 4):

Try The following Code, it might help

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

Comment: I am use this code but not working @PiyushSharma.notification receive only ios 9.